# checking if entered value is float, clearing cin

Tags: c++, double, cin

I have tried a few different variations of this code and I can't seem to get it right. I am pretty new to c++ yet so that might explain it. This code is part of a simple calculator. It basically asks the user to enter two numbers (they can be floats) and then asks the user for a mathematical operator and then does the operation. If a user enters something that's not a number and then enters a number when asked to enter a number again from the if statement the console prints "-9.25596e+061". This is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

double getUserInput()
{
    //Make double, assign double, return double if number
    double dUserInput;

    //checks if it failed to cin
    if (!(cin >> dUserInput))
    {
        //statement is true
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(99999, '\n');
        cout << "You did not enter a number, please try again: ";
        getUserInput();
    }else
        //statement if false
    cout << "Number entered"; //for debugging purposes
    return dUserInput;
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you print the value.

Comment: Are you distinguishing between numbers with decimal point and those without?  For example, the number 2 can be a `double` as well as an `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to add `return` in the recursive call to `getUserInput`.

Change the line

```
    getUserInput();
```

to

```
    return getUserInput();
```

**Update**

You can change the function to a non-recursive version.

```
double getUserInput()
{
    //Make double, assign double, return double if number
    double dUserInput;

    //checks if it failed to cin
    while (!(cin >> dUserInput))
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(99999, '\n');
        cout << "You did not enter a number, please try again: ";
    }

    cout << "Number entered"; //for debugging purposes
    return dUserInput;
}
```

Comment: Correct. But it's also worth noting that recursion is likely _not_ a good idea here.